# Horizontal Scroll bar not showing in Datagridview

Tags: visual-studio-2010, datagridview, horizontal-scrolling

Horizontal Scroll bar is not showing even after changing AutoSizeColumnMode setting to Column Header. 
Appreciate if someone let me know if there is a way to fix this problem by changing properties on DataGridView setting without writing any function in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accidentally have frozen couple of right columns in the DataGridView (in edit columns), that's why the horizontal bar was disappeared.